# Why does inline instantiation and addition of UserControl to StackPanel overwrite existing content?

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, instantiation, stackpanel

If I create instances of my UserControls, and then add them to the StackPanel like follows:

```
var myUC1 = new MyUserControl(GetControlData<Quick_Box>());
var myUC2 = new MyUserControl(GetControlData<Quick_Star>());
myStackPanel.Children.Add(myUC1);
myStackPanel.Children.Add(myUC2);
```

I can see that they're added, one after the other. However, if I don't create the instances beforehand, and attempt to create the instances as I'm adding them to the StackPanel as follows:

```
myStackPanel.Children.Add(new MyUserControl(GetControlData<Quick_Box>()));
myStackPanel.Children.Add(new MyUserControl(GetControlData<Quick_Star>()));
```

the second instance always overwrites the first. Why is this?

Comment: Can you post a short but complete program demonstrating the problem?#

Comment: There's no difference functionally between the two pieces of code, unless your `MyUserControl` or `GetControlData` code has something unexplained in it.  You say the second instance "overwrites" the first - what do you mean by that?  What do you see that leads you to that conclusion?  Have you *confirmed* that there is only a single child control (in Snoop or in your debugger), or do you only see one child control when you run the app and have assumed that the other doesn't exist?